# Empty DataSet with select query

Tags: c#, .net, dataset, oledb

I am using OleDb to query an Access database. The following query works in Access (as evidenced by the nested inner joins and many parentheses, Access actually built the query from the design GUI).  Apologies for the ugly table/column names.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.A, Table2.B, Table3.[C]
FROM (Table4 INNER JOIN (Table2 INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table2.ID = Table1.Table2ID) ON Table4.ID = Table1.Table4ID) INNER JOIN ((Table3 INNER JOIN Table5 ON Table3.ID = Table5.[Table3ID]) INNER JOIN Table6 ON Table3.ID = Table6.Table3ID) ON Table1.ID = Table6.Table1ID
WHERE (((Table1.D)=False) AND ((Table1.E)=True)))
```

It returns many rows.  However, the following code results in an empty data set.  There may be syntax errors due to the way the code is set up (a wrapper class handles some of these lines of code, so I had to unravel it for simplicity).

```
// db initialized prior
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(db);
con.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"
    SELECT DISTINCT Table1.A, Table2.B, Table3.[C]
    FROM (Table4 INNER JOIN (Table2 INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table2.ID = Table1.Table2ID) ON Table4.ID = Table1.Table4ID) INNER JOIN ((Table3 INNER JOIN Table5 ON Table3.ID = Table5.[Table3ID]) INNER JOIN Table6 ON Table3.ID = Table6.Table3ID) ON Table1.ID = Table6.Table1ID
    WHERE (((Table1.D)=False) AND ((Table1.E)=True)))
");
cmd.Connection = con;
DataSet data = new DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
adapter.Fill(data);
```

Other select queries executed on the database this way return data, so why is this returning an empty dataset?

Comment: Do you need to open the connection?

Comment: I'm sorry - that was a mistake in my unraveling of the code. I stepped through with the Visual Studio debugger and yes, the connection state is currently open at the time.  I will edit the code to reflect this.

Comment: You could do several things: 1. Check if there is any exception thrown (Menu "Debug", Exceptions..., Choose "CLR"-Exceptions) 2. Check if the connection is opened when executing the statement. 3. On an environment with multiple servers which have mirrored database structures, check if you are on the correct server and the correct database.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Some kind of unhandled exception or even one that's caught inside a `catch`?

Comment: I would try changing `WHERE (((Table1.D)=False) AND ((Table1.E)=True)))` to `WHERE ((Table1.D=False) AND (Table1.E=True)))`

Comment: I have no idea why it started returning data, but it did while I was stepping through the code with debugging all thrown exceptions turned on per Marco Klein's suggestion.

Comment: I did not have the DB open in Access, so I tried opening it in Access and then running the query in my program, thinking it might have been a resource conflict (which one would think would raise an exception), but the query worked.  I hadn't changed the program at all since I posted this question.  If anyone has any suggestions as to what conditions I can change (e.g. opening particular tables in Access while running the program) to try to duplicate the issue again please let me know and I'll create an answer if I'm able to duplicate it.

Comment: i have the same problem does somebody able to resolve it?